# Выбрать вектор с самым минимальным значением

Tags: c++

Есть двумерный вектор, там содержатся вектора, в которых лежит много различных позиций (0, 250) - к примеру, где 0 - X, а 250 - Y.

Таких позиций может быть множество.

Суть в чём: нужно выбрать вектор, который содержит в себе самую ближайшую позицию к точке (игроку).

P.S Формулу для вычисления ближайшей позиции знаю,

```
int GetDistanceBetween(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    double distance = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    return (int)distance;
}
```

но не могу понять, как взять вектор с самой ближайшей позицией.

Думал типа такого:

Брать и поочерёдно делать такие действия:

```
if (some_vector[0] > some_vector_two[0]){
   basic_vector.push_back(some_vector_two);
}
```

Надеюсь объяснил понятно)

Comment: Лично я ничего не понел.  По моему вам нужен просто вектор пар(если имеется ввиду хранение позиций на плоскости

Comment: Вы бы привели хотя бы минимальный код, ну и как выглядит ваш вектор, пока ведь ничего неясно. Все, что пока могу сказать - вызывать для возведения в квадрат `pow` - явно тяжеловесно, а для поиска минимального расстояния вполне можно не извлекать квадратный корень...

Answer (score 0):

Можете просто при проходе по вектору векторов применять вашу функцию для каждого вектора и запоминать минимальное значение функции + индекс того вектора, откуда вы его получили.

Либо организовать дополнительную структуру, которая будет хранить результаты вывода вашей функции. Тогда по этой структуре можно найти потом минимум (или изначально выбрать сортированную структуру).